# Which free HTML5-based game engine meets these requirements?

Tags: javascript, html5, browser-based-games

I am experienced with traditional JS and HTML but new to HTML5. I want to develop games in HTML5 so that it can work on all devices and browsers, including IE. Additionally, I require the following features:

- Physics Engine
- Animation
- Some AI
- Vector drawing and manipulation
- Better user/player controls, et cetera

I know there are many options, but just want some one that can give most flexibility... so I want some thing that can also be compiled to achieve maximum functionality.

One that is in my mind is GameKit; but please tell what you guys would suggest that meets my requirements.

Comment: I'd recommend you just use the raw HTML5 apis like `<canvas>` and slap on your IE shim of choice. That aside, [Lime](http://www.limejs.com/) and [impact](http://impactjs.com/) are the big players. Warning 2: any game you write will run like ass on IE<9.

Comment: ImpactJS isn't (or is no longer) free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [crafty.js](http://craftyjs.com/), it has a lot of the features you're looking for and is in active development.

Comment: So which way crafty.js? DOM or canvas? for some animation in game like where ground is shown from upside.

Comment: depends if you use fixed size or full screen. canvas takes a lot of memory when it's huge.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a list of lots of javascript [game engines](https://gist.github.com/768272). Out of those, I like crafty, Hydra and LimeJS

Answer (score 3):

[MelonJS](http://www.melonjs.org/) isn't bad either. And it works together with [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) for use of .tmx files. You can also layout your level and set up your collide-able tiles straight from within Tiled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Scirra and (of course!) would recommend you take a look at our [game maker, Construct 2](http://www.scirra.com).

It meets all the requirements you specify, however for the more complex ones like AI you would need to write your own JS plugins for this!

Here's a video showing how easy it is to add 2D physics to your games:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fASJyCABFMU&feature=channel_video_title

Also we offer a free edition which is very generous and should meet your requirements!

Comment: this is not free tool, it has a limited free and standard paid version , while I want some thing who has good parts in free also , not such limited free and paid for full version e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

The list that [Spooks](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19263/which-free-html5-based-game-engine-meets-these-requirements/19304#19304) posted is not up to date.

This is the same list, updated and wikified:
https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines

But what you are looking for exactly is this feature matrix:
https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-engine-feature-matrix

Feel free to add your own findings as the wiki is open for modification!

Comment: I can find a dozen of such lists but I came here so that I can find some thing that is also known to you guys and so that you guys can guide me to some thing good, but I think I should now just google, see such lists and experience many of them by myself